# How do I access an account associated with my email, but that I cannot log into?

Tags: support, status-completed, login

Sorry if this is posted in the wrong tag area. I couldn't find the correct tag and if anyone can help with that, it be great.

My problem is that a year ago I used a Stackoverflow account that was wired to my email. And over a year for some reason I made a new SO account, connected it with the same email and used that instead of the other one (I really can't explain why, I don't remember). That new SO account is *also* associated with my account. I know this because when I updated my [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/), I saw that my former SO account's thumbnail Gravatar changed as well:

[This is me:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/david)

[image]

[And this is my old account:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600905/david)

[image]

Notice how they have the same avatars. Also notice how *my* account has 4,982 reputation while the other has only 40 rep. (because I haven't had access to it in over a year!). **So my question is:** is there any way I can get access back to this account? They both are associated with the *same* email that I have access to. I know this because I remember getting email notifications from SO to my account notifying me of new answers to my question back when I had my old account. But now I don't get those notifications and I don't know why. But anyway, can you please give me any ideas as to how to get access to this account? Any and all suggestions are welcome. And if you need more detail please comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's enough similarity between the accounts that I was able to just go ahead and merge them for you.

In general, you'd use either the account recovery process or the [user merge help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: You merged them? Wow great! Does that mean that the answers and questions I posted in the old one are now added to the new one?

Comment: @David That's right. You basically now just have one account and all the things you ever posted under either one are assigned to it.

Comment: I can already see the change. Thank you so much!

Comment: @David No problem. :)